# How to fix element on the center of scrollable page?

Tags: html, css

For example, I have a webpage with huge height and it has a loader that normally gets up while scrolling. But I'd like  that loader to always stay on the center despite the scroll position. How can I do this?

**HTML**

```
<div class="loader"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  height: 1000vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.loader:before,
.loader:after,
.loader {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 2.5em;
  height: 2.5em;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation: load7 1.8s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: load7 1.8s infinite ease-in-out;
}
.loader {
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 80px auto;
  position: relative;
  text-indent: -9999em;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.16s;
  animation-delay: -0.16s;
}
.loader:before {
  left: -3.5em;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.32s;
  animation-delay: -0.32s;
}
.loader:after {
  left: 3.5em;
}
.loader:before,
.loader:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
@-webkit-keyframes load7 {
  0%,
  80%,
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 2.5em 0 -1.3em #C74038;
  }
  40% {
    box-shadow: 0 2.5em 0 0 #C74038;
  }
}
@keyframes load7 {
  0%,
  80%,
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 2.5em 0 -1.3em #C74038;
  }
  40% {
    box-shadow: 0 2.5em 0 0 #C74038;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, you do this by `position: fixed`, but then the margin trick to center does not work anymore, so you have to recenter.

Try changing you loader class into this:

```
.loader {
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 80px auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.16s;
  animation-delay: -0.16s;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);  
}
```

PS: I also think the `translateZ(0)` is not really needed here, as you already translateX this element. In case you wonder: `left: 50%` does center the element relative to the viewport, but only it's left edge. The translateX then does offset this by moving the element itself to the left, also by 50% but this time the 50% apply to the element width. This should perfectly center your element as a result.

PPS: and if you downvote, please explain why. Thank you.

Comment: I'm sure its just a copy paste error but you still have `position: relative` which is being overridden by the `position: fixed`.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I overlooked the "position: relative", but it should still work as the latter rule takes precendence. Corrected it though.

Answer (score 2):

Use `position: fixed`. This keeps it out of the flow of the document and at a fixed position relative to the viewport:

```
.loader {
  ...
  margin: 80px 50%;
  position: fixed;
  ...
}
```

Comment: This does not actually center the loader.

Comment: Nope not perfectly. I was mainly replying to the direct question of why does it not stay fixed when i scroll.